# Mahout & Lucene Version Compatibility

Tags: solr, lucene, mahout

I am trying to use Mahout to do some analysis on the term vectors stored in my Solr/Lucene index. Unfortunately, it seems that the latest Mahout release is behind the latest Solr/Lucene release.

My Solr/Lucene installation is 4.10.3. As far as I can tell, the latest Mahout release (1.0) expects Lucene indexes at version 4.6.1.

When I run `mahout lucene.vector` I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: MMapIndexInput(path="/path/to/data/index/segments.gen")): -3 (needs to be between -2 and -2)
```

I have tried two things so far to tackle this problem:

First, I edited my solrconfig.xml file to say:

```
<luceneMatchVersion>4.6.1</luceneMatchVersion>
```

delete my indexed data, and built a clean index from the original documents. This has done nothing to fix the error.

So secondly, I tried to change the `lucene.version` in the Mahout pom.xml file to 4.10.3 and recompile the binary to see if the capabilities had been added yet. I knew this was unlikely to work, but tried anyway.

My question is, how do I appropriately change the Lucene version that Solr uses for writing index files if it is not the above luceneMatchVersion setting in solrconfig.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Mahout seems to support Solr 3.x for now.  You may try this [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1112) for mahout.

Comment: That patch is several years old and is already part of the release version. Mahout currently supports Solr/Lucene 4.6.1 out of the box.